# rerender React js component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, rerender

I have to implement new UI to existing application with React js. This is react component which is rendered after menu item is clicked. I noticed that chrome dev tools plugin for react shows new component created each time the menu is clicked. 
Isn't it waste of memory?
this is menu activation code by Sammy.js

```
this.get('#/security',function(){
        this.swap("");
        React.render(
           <MainComponent/>,
           document.getElementById('content')
       );
    });
```

Answer (score 5):

Yea you should only `React.render` once. Try something like:

```
React.render(<App />, document.getElementById('content'));

const App = React.createClass({
  getInitialState() {
    return { loaded: false };
  },

  componentDidMount() {
    this.get('#/security',function(){
      this.swap("");
      this.setState({ loaded: true });  
    });
  },

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        {this.state.loaded ? <MainComponent /> : null}
      </div>
    );
  }
});
```

Comment: ok, but after click on other menu item content page is overwritten so if I click to previous menu item back I need to re-render it again.

Answer (score 0):

According to the [React top-level API documentation](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/top-level-api.html#reactdom.render):

> If the ReactElement was previously rendered into container, this will perform an update on it and only mutate the DOM as necessary to reflect the latest React component.

So re-rendering shouldn't create a new component, but rather update the previous one.

Depending on your use-case you may want to handle the menu click inside your React app or component and update state internally and re-render, but that may not be possible in your case.

Answer (score 0):

forceUpdate() after state had changed might solve the problem of manual rendering the components.

```
  this.forceUpdate();//manually renders components of each time the state changed
```